# JSON não está retornando com os acentos

Tags: java-ee, spring, spring-boot, restful

Estou com uma dúvida que não sei mais o que fazer para ele vir sem zuar os acentos, já tentei várias formas colocar anotação do Spring dom Procudes UFT-8 nenhuma solução deu jeito.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public ResponseEntity<UsuarioSaidaDTO> saveUsuario (UsuarioEntradaDTO usuarioEntradaDTO) {

    UsuarioSaidaDTO usuarioSaidaDTO = new UsuarioSaidaDTO();

    try {

        if (usuarioEntradaDTO.getCodigoTipoUsuario() == 1) {
            Usuario usuarioFindByCodigoTipoUsuarioAdmistrador = usuarioRepository.findByCodigoTipoUsuarioAdmistrador();

            if (usuarioFindByCodigoTipoUsuarioAdmistrador != null) {
                usuarioSaidaDTO.setCode(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.USUARIO_JA_EXISTE_ADMINISTRADOR.getCode());
                usuarioSaidaDTO.setMessage(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.USUARIO_JA_EXISTE_ADMINISTRADOR.getMessage());

                return new ResponseEntity<UsuarioSaidaDTO>(usuarioSaidaDTO, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }

        Usuario usuarioFindByLoginUsuario = usuarioRepository.findByLoginUsuario(usuarioEntradaDTO.getLoginUsuario());

        if (usuarioFindByLoginUsuario != null) {
            usuarioSaidaDTO.setCode(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.USUARIO_JA_EXISTE_LOGIN.getCode());
            usuarioSaidaDTO.setMessage(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.USUARIO_JA_EXISTE_LOGIN.getMessage());

            return new ResponseEntity<UsuarioSaidaDTO>(usuarioSaidaDTO, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        Usuario usuario = ConvertToBean.convertToUsuario(usuarioEntradaDTO);

        usuarioRepository.save(usuario);

        usuarioSaidaDTO.setCode(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.INCLUIR.getCode());
        usuarioSaidaDTO.setMessage(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.INCLUIR.getMessage());



        return ResponseEntity.ok(usuarioSaidaDTO);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        usuarioSaidaDTO.setCode(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.ERRO_GERAL.getCode());
        usuarioSaidaDTO.setMessage(BusinessRulesReturnCodes.ERRO_GERAL.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<UsuarioSaidaDTO>(usuarioSaidaDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como tá a saída?

Comment: Resolvi, tirando as mensagens do Java, e colocando somente no Angular assim resolveu todos os meus problemas, eu só retorno o tipo de retorno agora, verifico no Angular e coloco a mensagem que eu quero.